# get how many animation I have in my presentation

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint

I want to create a button where counts how many animation/effects has each slice in presentations. I want to put a limit of animations so I need to know how much are in each one. Can it be make with VBA?

Comment: I think it's possible... Which animation do you have in mind?  Do you want to count each item in your 'animation window'??

Comment: I want to catch every animations I have...  But i found something that could work. Now i don't have the laptop with me so i cannot test it. Tomorrow i will check and put here if it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution of this problem:

```
  For Each slid In ActivePresentation.Slides
      If slid.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count >= 1 Then
        MsgBox "Number of animations per slide: " + Str(slid.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count)
    End If
  Next
```

With this you can count how much animations we have in our presentation

Answer (score 0):

More simply, to get one number of all of the animations in a Slide Show use

```
Dim count As Integer
count = 0
For Each slid In ActivePresentation.Slides
    If slid.TimeLine.MainSequence.count >= 1 Then
        count = count + slid.TimeLine.MainSequence.count
    End If
Next
MsgBox Str(count) + " number of animations"
```